# Java if statement comparison of 2 values

Tags: java, string

I'm having a slight problem that i can't understand, i'm building a Web Server that handles calls in the java E.G go to use /SendCommand.html then Java will handle the request, i have a login system built using post, but for some reason my login check is not working,

```
private boolean checkLogin(String user, String pass){
    for(int i = 0; i < users.users.length; i++ ){
        String test = SHA1.toSHA1(pass);
        if(users.users[i][0] == user && users.users[i][1] == test ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm Breaking at the if statment to provide the information below When i debug this i get,

```
Name            | Type            | Value
users             Users             #163
  users           String[]          #165(length=1)
    [0]           String[]          #167
      [0]         String            "Admin"
      [1]         String            "d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997"
user              String            "Admin"
pass              String            "admin"
test              String            "d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997"
```

As you can see `users.users[0][0] == user` and `users.users[0][1] == test` why is it returning false from the method?

Comment: it's not a duplicate im looking for help with a specific problem in my code not what's the difference between .equals and == i did not think it would make a difference in Java like it does not in most Objecting C langs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare strings. Use [`s1.equals(s2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead. The former compares references, which is almost always not what you want. The latter, on the other hand, compares character sequences.

Comment: Thanks for all the details i think that it's flaming retarded that a C language does not support string comparison the same why most Objective C languages do, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(users.users[i][0].equals(user) && users.users[i][1].equals(test))
```

Always compare String with .equals()